# Is there is process for getting instant payment from authorized.net using recurring billing system?

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I want to make a code that get instant payment by user . 
Example :

user subscribe on 11/march/2014 of amount $40 then system will charge $40 instantly for the subscription fees of April.

And then subscription start date set to 1/May/2014 ( Because we already charged user for April ).

Any Idea ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want an instant payment to start a subscription you need to use the Advanced Integration Method (AIM) API. Then after the payment is successful you can set up your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a monthly subscription, the ISubscriptionRequest.StartsOn is the date upon which billing will begin.

```
ISubscriptionGateway arbGate = new AuthorizeNet.SubscriptionGateway(logID, transID, ServiceMode.Live);
ISubscriptionRequest arbReq = SubscriptionRequest.CreateMonthly(txtEmail.Text, description, Convert.ToDecimal(txtAmount.Text), 9999);

arbReq.CardNumber = txtCardNumber.Text;
arbReq.BillingAddress = new Address
{
    First = firstName,
    Last = lastName,
    Street = txtAddress.Text,
    City = txtCity.Text,
    State = txtState.Text,
    Zip = txtZip.Text,
    Country = txtCountry.Text
};

arbReq.CardExpirationMonth = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonthExpire.SelectedValue);
arbReq.CardExpirationYear = Convert.ToInt32(rbm.toStr(ddlYearExpire.SelectedItem.Text));
arbReq.CardCode = txtCVV.Text;
arbReq.CustomerEmail = txtEmail.Text;
arbReq.StartsOn = dateStart;
```